# How to send some data to fragment when it popped from backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity with container for fragments. *Fragment1* is for example list of products. On search action, i replace container with *Fragment2* (search-filter panel) and need on back-button send some data to popped from backstack *Fragment1*. How to do that ? I have static `create` method on all fragments (with `setArguments` use), but i don't want to create new instance. Maybe i've something missed in using of fragments, but know only about `setArguments` method, but this method is only usable to creating new instances of fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the Data in the MainActivity and read it from any Fragment like:

```
//MainActivity
private String mSearchItem;

public void getSearchItem(){
    return this.mSearchItem;
}

public void setSearchItem(String searchItem){
    this.mSearchItem = searchItem;
}


//FRAGMENT 1
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    String item = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSearchItem();
    //if item != null do some crazy shizzle
    //set MainActivity searchitem to null to avoid reloading it
}



//FRAGMENT 2
private void setData(String searchItem){
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSearchItem(searchItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Communications between fragments should always be done via the activity, as they should be totally independent from each other.

Comment: I'm using `Otto` (event bus) for some sort of actions (REST service access). Is usable in that situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Any communication between two fragments of same activity should be done through activity only, make use of getActivity() method, create an interface and implement it inside the activity

Comment: And now it's better to use requireActivity()

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data with variables in your activity which your fragments attach and in your previous fragment's onResume() you can restore it from your activity and use it.